# Многопользовательская аутентификация в Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Сейчас пытаюсь настроить  SecurityConfig класс для авторизации в приложении для  двух разных класов (User, Employee). Я создал в классе конфиге два статических класса и отметил их анотацией Order().

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SquirrelSecurityConfig  {
//конфигурация для пользователя
 @Configuration
 @Order(1)
public class UserSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Autowired
 private H2ConsoleProperties console; 
 @Autowired
 private UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;

 @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/","/registration", "/test","/css/**","/js/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
     .antMatchers("/employee/**").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
   .and()
     // указание формы для аутентификации
     .formLogin()
     .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_user") 
     .loginPage("/login")
     .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/home" )
     .failureUrl("/login?error_user=true")
     .usernameParameter("login")
     .passwordParameter("hashPass")
     .permitAll()
     .and()
     // указание страницы отображающейся при выходе
     .logout()
     .logoutUrl("/logout")
     .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
     .deleteCookies("remember-me")
     .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
     .permitAll()
     .and()
     .rememberMe()
     .and().csrf().disable();
 }
 @Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new 
BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
}
//конфигурация для сотрудника
 @Configuration
 @Order(2)
 public class EmployeeSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Autowired
 private EmployeeDetailServiceImpl employeeDetailServiceImpl;
 @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // предостовление доступа к адресам, определенным ролям
        http.authorizeRequests()
     // добавление шаблонов страниц, требующих авторизации
     .antMatchers("/","/registration", "/test","/css/**","/js/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/employee/**").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
   .and()
     // указание формы для аутентификации
     .formLogin()
     .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_employee") 
     .loginPage("/login")
     .defaultSuccessUrl("/employee/home" )
     .failureUrl("/login?error_employee=true")
     .usernameParameter("login")
     .passwordParameter("hashPass")
     .permitAll()
     .and()
     // указание страницы отображающейся при выходе
     .logout()
     .logoutUrl("/logout")
     .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
     .deleteCookies("remember-me")
     .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
     .permitAll()
     .and()
     .rememberMe()
     .and().csrf().disable();
 }
 @Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(employeeDetailServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(new 
BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
}
}
```

Для каждого класса который хочу сконфигурировать сделал UserDetailService  (для Employee класс аналогичен)

```
  @Service
  public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService  {
  @Autowired
  private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws 
UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userServiceImpl.findOneByLogin(login).orElseThrow(() -> new 
UsernameNotFoundException("user not found"));
    // указываем роли для этого пользователя
  Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<>();
    user.getRoles().forEach(role->roles.add(new 
   SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())) );
    UserDetails userDetails =  new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(),user.getHashРass(),  roles);

    return userDetails;
}
}
```

На странице с логином две формы одно отправляет запрос на **"/j_spring_security_user"** вторая на **"/j_spring_security_employee"**

```
 <form  th:action="@{/j_spring_security_user}"  th:object="${user}" method='POST'>
   <div class="row">
     <input type="text"  th:field="*{login}" name="j_username">
     <input type="password"   th:field="*{hashPass}" name="j_password">
     <button class="btn btn-common"  type="submit">Войти</button> 
   </div>
</form>
<form  th:action="@{/j_spring_security_employee}"  th:object="${employee}" method='POST'>
 <div class="row">
    <input type="text"  th:field="*{login}" name="j_username">
    <input type="password"   th:field="*{hashPass}" name="j_password">
    <button class="btn btn-common"  type="submit">Войти</button> 
</div>
```

Ситуация у меня следующая, со страницы логина я могу зайти под User, а когда пытаюсь зайти под Employee то застреваю в Order(1) и не дохожу до Order(2).
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Зачем вообще 2 формы? Когда будет 10 ролей, вы 10 раз то же самое будете прописывать?

Comment: Пока необходимо реализовать так